# list check logic in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list like below.

```
empList = ['one','two','finish','one','three']
```

I need to check condition from empList

scenario 1: if list order 'two' is coming before 'finish' I have to make `this.beforeCheckFlag = true`

scenario 2: if list order 'two' is coming after 'finish' I have to make `this.afterCheckFlag = true`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqe5Jm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use here [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store the `emp` as `key` and `index` as `value` as:

```js
const empList = ['one', 'two', 'finish', 'one', 'three'];
const map = new Map(empList.map((emp, index) => [emp, index]));

// If 'two' comes before 'finish' then its index will be lesser
const beforeCheckFlag = map.get('two') < map.get('finish');
console.log(beforeCheckFlag);

// If 'two' comes before 'finish' then its index will be greater
const afterCheckFlag = map.get('two') > map.get('finish');
console.log(afterCheckFlag);
```